# How to send a table row data without using any scripting in servlet?

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

```
List<Employee> records = employeeServicable.printAll();
int size = records.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    htmlRespone.append("<tr> " + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getId() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getName() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getDepartment() + "</td>"+ 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getPhoneNumber() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getHireDate() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getJob() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getEducationLevel() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getGender() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + records.get(i).getDateOfBirth() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + Integer.toString(records.get(i).getSalary()) + "</td>"
        + "</tr>");
}
htmlRespone.append("</table");
```

How can I send a specific row data to a servlet? I will attach a button at the end of each column but how will that button do it?

Comment: I need to do this by using only html and servlet. Part of my training.

Comment: Maybe by using `a` tag and pass your `records.get(i).getId()` with it ..so that you can get the `id` and fetch the data depend on that `id` in `doGet()` method .

Comment: @Swati I think you are right. I will try this.